# Add or declare two plotOptions in highcharts for Synchronized chart

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

How can I change second chart color to green for value between 150 to 500?
at the first chart I use plotOptions to declare zone to change color to green.
But I have a second plotOptions (If Possible) for second  chart to change the color between 150 to 550 to green run the cod to find-out what I have! 
and another questions id when i have a lot point Json cannot pars ! for this solution i create Json From Server and passed to chart by $.getJSON('/home/GetChartDataFromThisDay' but problem is still exist!
i have about 25/000 point to show in chart. what should be do?

```js
$('#container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function (e) {
    var chart,
        point,
        i,
        event;

    for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i = i + 1) {
        chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
        event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent); // Find coordinates within the chart
        point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(event, true); // Get the hovered point

        if (point) {
            point.highlight(e);
        }
    }
});
/**
 * Override the reset function, we don't need to hide the tooltips and crosshairs.
 */
Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function () {
    return undefined;
};

/**
 * Highlight a point by showing tooltip, setting hover state and draw crosshair
 */
Highcharts.Point.prototype.highlight = function (event) {
    this.onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
    this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this); // Show the tooltip
    this.series.chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, this); // Show the crosshair
};

/**
 * Synchronize zooming through the setExtremes event handler.
 */
function syncExtremes(e) {
    var thisChart = this.chart;

    if (e.trigger !== 'syncExtremes') { // Prevent feedback loop
        Highcharts.each(Highcharts.charts, function (chart) {
            if (chart !== thisChart) {
                if (chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes) { // It is null while updating
                    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(e.min, e.max, undefined, false, { trigger: 'syncExtremes' });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

var t='{"xData":[0.001567,0.011765,0.022194,0.032316,0.04266,0.063668,0.074477,0.085323,0.09576,0.106078,0.116096,0.137524,0.148342,0.159059,0.170005,0.180716,0.191407,0.212538,0.222819,0.233929,0.244239,0.255301,0.266081,0.287527,0.298115,0.309392,0.320217,0.330928,0.341401,0.361717,0.372173,0.382337,0.39294,0.403072,0.413454,0.434618,0.444845,0.455745,0.465785,0.475987,0.486064,0.507086,0.517517,0.527961,0.538242,0.548414,0.558444,0.578941,0.589212,0.599472,0.60977,0.620178,0.630189,0.650782,0.661001,0.671137,0.681175,0.691235,0.702012,0.722644,0.733166,0.743824,0.754059,0.764109,0.774519,0.795597,0.805721,0.81592,0.826139,0.836369,0.846826,0.86771,0.87803,0.888342,0.898695,0.908723,0.91922,0.939802,0.950378,0.960776,0.971377,0.981843,0.992312,1.013125,1.023302,1.033488,1.043822,1.054203,1.065019,1.086078,1.09635,1.106421,1.117028,1.127541,1.138599,1.159588,1.170167,1.180741,1.190794,1.201112,1.211355,1.233278,1.243477,1.254957,1.265227,1.276378,1.285656,1.297311,1.308367,1.318715,1.329589,1.340834,1.352388,1.375063,1.385369,1.396291,1.408156,1.418989,1.429535,1.451141,1.462205,1.473011,1.483844,1.494311,1.514761,1.525336,1.535858,1.546476,1.557325,1.567512,1.590091,1.600925,1.612303,1.622558,1.633071,1.643555,1.66484,1.675722,1.685986,1.696733,1.706895,1.719102,1.741295,1.752144,1.762688,1.773713,1.784052,1.795705,1.817305,1.827465,1.838408,1.849369,1.860023,1.871438,1.89257,1.90323,1.914398,1.924634,1.934642,1.945212,1.966275,1.976294,1.986422,1.996652,2.008005,2.018309,2.041139,2.051221,2.0613,2.072507,2.08342,2.094075,2.114574,2.125286,2.135765,2.146845,2.157966,2.169391,2.190921,2.200899,2.212709,2.222671,2.232908,2.244001,2.264898,2.275703,2.286885,2.298115,2.310186,2.32059,2.344695,2.354843,2.366387,2.379001,2.390328,2.402215,2.423134,2.433156,2.444912,2.457061,2.468253,2.478978,2.499832,2.513223,2.52561,2.538429,2.548659,2.560809,2.581308,2.592816,2.603963,2.615992,2.626242,2.638223,2.660346,2.671583,2.681938,2.69265,2.70588,2.716296,2.740081,2.75085,2.761319,2.772027,2.782659,2.793531,2.816194,2.828031,2.839243,2.851443,2.863884,2.874359,2.895246,2.906506,2.91761,2.92786,2.938937,2.950218,2.973357,2.98366,2.994639,3.005213,3.01666,3.02761,3.050025,3.061713,3.071828,3.082787,3.093422,3.105289,3.127231,3.138982,3.149755,3.160217,3.171299,3.191571,3.202226,3.213225,3.223987,3.234092,3.244644,3.265939,3.276411,3.286489,3.297156,3.307909,3.319018,3.34064,3.351107,3.361683,3.373136,3.384768,3.395457,3.417722,3.429096,3.439122,3.449679,3.459868,3.469997,3.492679,3.503647,3.514941,3.525858,3.538746,3.550422,3.572255,3.58452,3.595367,3.605736,3.617401,3.628324,3.652523,3.663679,3.67378,3.684605,3.695595,3.705843,3.728706,3.739169,3.750205,3.761258,3.771771,3.781911,3.804724,3.81631,3.826313,3.837847,3.85049,3.860999,3.88262,3.892937,3.903053,3.913656,3.924698,3.935126,3.956362,3.966543,3.976899,3.98752,3.997644,4.008721,4.029852,4.040633,4.051006,4.06126,4.071761,4.083526,4.10749,4.117855,4.128661,4.13934,4.151117,4.1624,4.184736,4.194826,4.205098,4.215261,4.225325,4.236367,4.262012,4.273794,4.285743,4.297226,4.308086,4.318245,4.340246,4.351486,4.363196,4.374465,4.387109,4.398635,4.421101,4.432135,4.444666,4.456226,4.467413,4.477804,4.498505,4.510413,4.522595,4.534044,4.545944,4.558048,4.580379,4.59312,4.605616,4.618065,4.631266,4.644086,4.667943,4.67948,4.691266,4.703019,4.715923,4.725932,4.752312,4.765224,4.777128,4.787361,4.800435,4.823353,4.836044,4.848602,4.860302,4.871112,4.882779,4.904695,4.914823,4.927074,4.938111,4.949586,4.960761,4.982911,4.9942,5.004246,5.016296,5.027215,5.038043,5.058885,5.070303,5.080649,5.093865,5.104424,5.114903,5.134965,5.146346,5.15634,5.168547,5.179066,5.191167,5.214242,5.224914,5.237573,5.249537,5.261586,5.272517,5.296154,5.306348,5.316773,5.327153,5.339961,5.350638,5.376502,5.389277,5.402142,5.412197,5.42399,5.434873,5.458466,5.470907,5.482679,5.493339,5.50574,5.516349,5.538897,5.549552,5.56083,5.571879,5.583764,5.59509,5.619028,5.629925,5.640716,5.650957,5.661787,5.671957,5.693974,5.704919,5.717491,5.731152,5.744728,5.755687,5.778668,5.791951,5.80409,5.815697,5.828482,5.840501,5.864145,5.875704,5.887893,5.900147,5.912517,5.924894,5.948897,5.959155,5.970262,5.981632,5.992996,6.00356,6.027256,6.038776,6.050959,6.061351,6.071864,6.082436,6.104054,6.115602,6.127623,6.139058,6.150639,6.161323,6.183013,6.194359,6.206269,6.218033,6.2281,6.240494,6.262584,6.275326,6.287166,6.298953,6.310644,6.321583,6.345676,6.356738,6.366782,6.377931,6.388519,6.397159],"datasets": [{"name": "دما","data":[13.833,12.524,11.441,10.651,9.961,4.566,4.617,4.728,4.823,4.844,4.856,4.87,4.702,4.679,4.674,4.641,4.47,4.688,4.798,4.756,4.903,4.919,5.017,4.938,4.879,4.831,4.623,3.887,3.502,3.083,3.123,3.073,2.922,2.827,2.805,2.605,2.743,2.698,2.513,2.41,2.17,2.288,2.308,2.222,2.183,2.224,2.163,2.223,2.142,2.257,2.015,1.971,1.894,1.848,1.835,1.85,2.036,1.827,1.904,1.803,1.852,1.866,1.906,1.956,1.954,1.734,1.904,1.899,2.001,1.966,1.844,1.879,1.856,1.837,1.827,1.907,1.729,1.74,1.68,1.797,1.811,1.941,2.026,2.217,2.281,2.517,2.673,2.702,2.893,3.016,3.073,3.126,3.283,3.361,3.33,3.465,3.916,4.49,5.074,5.717,6.523,7.012,6.726,7.095,7.471,7.824,7.802,4.441,4.625,4.696,4.861,4.768,4.889,5.281,5.36,5.419,5.137,5.278,5.151,4.934,4.952,4.742,4.666,4.525,4.126,4.228,4.334,4.383,5.287,5.088,5.28,5.274,5.251,5.413,5.365,5.372,5.512,4.839,5.099,5.196,5.219,5.094,5.582,5.91,5.952,6.012,5.854,5.789,5.465,5.525,5.659,5.67,5.173,5.033,5.318,5.289,5.226,5.15,5.106,4.989,5.103,5.288,5.428,5.363,5.026,5,4.941,4.872,4.751,4.408,4.425,4.301,4.134,4.171,4.272,4.34,4.543,4.826,5.381,5.374,5.433,5.483,5.539,5.869,6.956,7.443,7.654,8.005,8.181,8.386,9.202,9.51,9.66,9.141,8.79,8.747,8.949,9.188,9.625,10.154,10.173,10.361,11.186,11.226,11.091,10.899,10.945,10.892,9.618,9.092,8.465,7.864,7.396,7.076,7.053,6.772,6.958,7.202,6.93,6.857,7.007,7.059,7.099,7.025,6.95,7.116,6.331,6.39,6.571,6.571,6.604,6.407,6.371,6.348,6.348,5.995,6.162,6.287,6.241,6.033,6.083,6.313,6.118,5.78,5.698,5.804,5.743,5.655,5.976,6.005,6.06,5.988,6.021,6.049,5.882,5.296,5.142,4.701,4.701,4.647,4.491,4.48,4.384,4.263,4.515,4.721,5.084,6.225,6.302,6.409,6.52,6.462,6.525,6.816,6.656,6.566,6.34,6.177,6.143,7.462,7.783,7.885,7.998,8.182,8.352,8.32,8.5,8.967,8.474,8.178,7.89,7.436,7.634,7.777,7.628,7.189,6.787,6.048,6.003,6.189,6.216,6.389,6.353,7.341,7.899,7.849,7.757,7.314,7.134,6.858,6.689,6.526,5.909,5.138,4.617,4.339,4.558,4.493,4.545,4.419,4.245,4.468,5.093,5.737,6.215,6.613,6.876,7.566,7.586,7.901,7.736,7.23,6.703,5.896,5.73,6.032,6.263,6.458,7.107,7.766,7.911,7.794,7.776,7.876,7.866,7.462,7.298,6.898,6.62,6.747,7.285,8.139,8.411,8.776,8.946,9.155,9.296,10.15,9.96,9.885,9.99,10.203,10.401,10.935,11.071,11.274,11.566,11.851,12.187,12.363,12.426,12.478,12.486,12.117,12.132,11.791,11.332,11.441,11.38,11.309,10.985,10.627,10.355,9.899,9.833,9.747,9.693,9.514,9.502,9.888,9.98,10.255,10.667,10.531,10.452,10.267,10.2,10.437,10.553,10.577,10.661,11.022,11.213,11.311,11.572,11.708,11.176,10.857,10.754,10.629,10.185,10.052,10.083,10.31,10.478,10.626,11.121,11.141,11.221,11.299,11.435,11.599,11.353,11.299,11.288,11.279,11.208,11.307,11.685,11.58,11.379,11.096,11.144,10.947,10.699,10.881,10.746,10.276,9.994,9.629,9.76,9.749,10.012,10.184,10.336,10.473,10.848,11.349,11.978,12.167,12.327,12.339,12.064,12.09,12.12,11.94,11.562,11.208,10.974,10.948,10.983,10.76,10.694,10.534,10.273,10.364,10.421,10.357,10.316,10.472,10.94,11.314,11.485,11.488,11.606,11.479,11.091,11.288,11.354,11.501,11.302,10.968,11.026,10.944,11.08,11.388,11.504,11.279,10.683,10.533,10.505,10.305,10.146,10.148,9.501,9.366,9.23,9.067,8.956,8.935],"unit": "°C","type": "line","valueDecimals": 1}, {"name":"رطوبت","data":[26.857,27,27.111,27.2,27.272,30.545,32.181,33.818,35.272,36.545,37.818,41.818,44.545,47.272,48.545,49.818,53.545,61,64.909,68.818,72.727,75.09,77.454,82.181,84.545,84.454,86.181,87.909,89.636,93.09,96.727,100.363,104,107.636,111.272,116.727,121.09,125.454,129.818,134.181,136.727,151.636,159.09,166.545,174,181.454,186.363,201.636,209.272,216.909,222.818,228.727,234.636,249.363,258.181,267,273.09,279.181,288.181,303,308.818,314.636,326.909,336.272,345.636,364.363,373.727,380.181,389.818,399.454,409.09,425.727,432.727,439.727,446.727,453.727,460.727,473.272,478.818,484.363,489.909,491.636,493.363,498.272,500.727,503.181,506.454,508,509.545,512.636,514.363,516.09,517.909,519.727,521.545,525.636,527.272,528.909,529.636,530.363,530.909,531.181,531.3,531.444,530.75,529.857,528.666,521,521,521.777,522.4,522.909,522.818,522.636,522.545,522.454,522.363,522.272,522.181,520.727,520.545,521.09,521.636,522.181,523.272,523.818,524.363,524.909,525.454,528.09,532.272,534.363,536.454,537.909,539.363,540.818,543.727,545.909,544.818,543.727,542.636,541.545,540,539.545,539.09,538.636,537.272,535.181,533.363,532.454,531.545,530.636,529.727,528.818,526.272,525.909,525.545,525.181,524.818,524.454,523.727,522.363,521,520,519,516.545,511.636,510.636,509.636,506.909,504.181,502.454,499,497.272,497,496.727,497.454,496.727,493.818,491.636,489.454,487.272,487.09,486.909,486.545,485.363,484.181,484.09,481.545,479,478.181,477.909,477.636,477.363,477.09,476.818,476.363,481.818,487.272,492.727,493.909,493.181,491.727,491,490.272,489.545,487.636,485.727,482.363,474.454,468.454,462.454,456.454,450.454,439.727,435,430.272,425.545,418.727,418.363,418.545,419.09,419.636,420.181,419.454,418.727,413.818,413,412.181,411.363,409.636,407.909,405,403.818,397.454,392.818,388.181,383.545,374.272,369.636,365,358.363,351.181,344,340,338,336,334,332,328.636,323.909,322.545,321.181,319.818,318.272,315.181,313.636,312.09,311.909,311.727,310.545,308.181,307,306,305,302.818,300.636,297.545,296.636,296.727,296.181,295.636,295.09,294,294.636,293.09,291.545,291.545,291.545,292.181,292.818,293.454,294.09,292.545,291,292.272,292.363,292.454,292.545,289.818,287.09,281.636,281.09,280.545,277,273.454,271.454,267.454,265.181,262.909,260.636,258.363,256.09,248.909,246.818,240.909,235,229.09,226.272,220.636,217.818,215,215,211.545,208.09,201.181,197.727,194.272,190.818,187.363,183.909,170.818,173,175.181,177.363,179.545,181.727,186.09,182.727,179.363,179.09,178.818,173.272,160.272,152.818,145.363,137.909,130.454,126.818,116.272,111,107.363,101.909,98.363,94.818,87,82.818,80.363,79.545,78.272,77,73,71.454,69.636,67.909,66.727,65.454,62.909,62.09,61.272,60.363,59.454,59,58.545,58.272,58.09,57.909,57.727,57.545,57.272,57.181,56.909,56.636,56.454,56.272,55.909,55.727,55.818,55.545,55.272,54.909,54.818,54.727,54.636,54.545,54.454,54,54,54,54,54,53.636,52.909,52.545,52.636,52.727,52.818,52.909,52.636,52.272,52.272,52.272,52.272,52.818,53,53.09,53.181,53.272,53.818,54.363,55.09,55.454,55.272,55.09,54.909,54.727,54.363,53.727,53.09,52.636,52.181,51.727,50.818,50.363,50.363,50.363,50.363,50.818,51.727,51.272,50.818,50.363,50.636,50.909,50.545,50.363,50.181,50,49.818,50.818,52.818,53.09,53.363,53.636,53.909,54.181,53.272,52.818,52.09,51.363,50.636,49.909,47.818,46.09,44.363,43.363,42.363,41.363,39.363,37.636,35.909,35.181,35.09,35.363,35.909,36.181,36.545,36.909,37.272,38.363,39.545,39.636,39.727,39.818,38.636,37.454,34.909,33.636,32.363,31.09,29.818,27.181,21.909,20.545,19.181,17.818,16.454,15.09,10.727,8.545,8.636,8.727,8.818,8.909,9.09,8.9,8.666,9.5,10.571,12],"unit": "%","type": "line","valueDecimals": 0}]}';
var obj = JSON.parse(t);
// Get the data. The contents of the data file can be viewed at
// https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/samples/data/activity.json
    $.each(obj.datasets, function (i, dataset) {
        dataset.data = Highcharts.map(dataset.data, function (val, j) {
            return [obj.xData[j], val];
        });

        $('<div class="chart">')
            .appendTo('#container')
            .highcharts({
                chart: {
                    marginLeft: 40, // Keep all charts left aligned
                    spacingTop: 20,
                    spacingBottom: 20,
                    zoomType: 'x'
                },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            zones: [{
                value: 3,
                className: 'zone-2'
            }, {
                value: 10,
                className: 'zone-1'
            }, {
                className: 'zone-2'
            }],
        }
    },
                title: {
                    text: dataset.name,
                    align: 'left',
                    margin: 0,
                    x: 30
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                xAxis: {
                
                    crosshair: true,
                    events: {
                        setExtremes: syncExtremes
                    },
                    labels: {
                        format: '{value} ساعت'
                    }
                },
                yAxis: [{
                plotLines: [{ 
                label: {
                    text: 'max',
                    x: 25
                },
                color: 'red',
                width: 2,
                value: 10,
                dashStyle: 'longdashdot'
            },{ 
                label: {
                    text: 'min',
                    x: 25
                },
                color: 'red',
                width: 2,
                value: 3,
                dashStyle: 'longdashdot'
            }],
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    }
                },{
                plotLines: [{ 
                label: {
                    text: 'max',
                    x: 25
                },
                color: 'red',
                width: 2,
                value: 550,
                dashStyle: 'longdashdot'
            },{ 
                label: {
                    text: 'min',
                    x: 25
                },
                color: 'red',
                width: 2,
                value: 150,
                dashStyle: 'longdashdot'
            }],
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    }
                },{
                plotLines: [{ 
                label: {
                    text: 'max',
                    x: 25
                },
                color: 'red',
                width: 2,
                value: 125,
                dashStyle: 'longdashdot'
            },{ 
                label: {
                    text: 'min',
                    x: 25
                },
                color: 'blue',
                width: 2,
                value: 50,
                dashStyle: 'longdashdot'
            }],
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    }
                }],
                tooltip: {
                    positioner: function () {
                        return {
                            x: this.chart.chartWidth - this.label.width, // right aligned
                            y: 10 // align to title
                        };
                    },
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    backgroundColor: 'none',
                    pointFormat: '{point.y}',
                    headerFormat: '',
                    shadow: false,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '18px'
                    },
                    valueDecimals: dataset.valueDecimals
                },
                series: [{
                    data: dataset.data,
                    name: dataset.name,
                    type: dataset.type,
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i],
                    yAxis:i,
                    fillOpacity: 0.3,
                    tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: ' ' + dataset.unit
                    }
                }]
            });
    });
```

```css
#container {
 min-width: 310px;
 max-width: 800px;
 height: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto
}
.highcharts-point {
 stroke: white;
}

.highcharts-graph.zone-0 {
 stroke: red;
}
.highcharts-area.zone-0 {
 fill: red;
}
.highcharts-point.zone-0 {
 fill: red;
}
.highcharts-graph.zone-1 {
 stroke: green;
}
.highcharts-area.zone-1 {
 fill: green;
}
.highcharts-point.zone-1 {
 fill: green;
}
.highcharts-graph.zone-2 {
 stroke: red;
}
.highcharts-area.zone-2 {
 fill: red;
}
.highcharts-point.zone-2 {
 fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same values for `zones` in both charts. You need to change their values on each chart creation.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Highcharts.setOptions

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8u0k32et/